# How to match column id while importing file from Excel into SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables in my database:

1. `USERTABLE`
2. `DEPARTMENT`

`Department`'s foreign key is referencing the `Usertable` as shown in this screenshot:

[image: DATABASE Screenshot]

I have already added department names in departmenttable.
[Department/Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2WUQ.png)

now when i go to usertable an click on upload excel file. when i click uppload it gives me an error

"errorThe given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column."

[Usertable/adduser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFkQ2.png)

In the `usertable` I have an import button which imports an Excel file, reads the data and enters it into the database. Everything is uploading correctly BUT problem is that which it time to upload the department column as a string "IT HAS TO MATCH THE DEPARTMENT'S ""ID"""and then it has to enter in the database.

HOW SHOULD I MATCH THE DEPARTMENT STRING with DEPARTMENT ID ? Please guide

```
public ActionResult ImportFromExcel(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > (1024 * 1024 * 50))  // 50MB limit  
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("postedFile", "Your file is to large. Maximum size allowed is 50MB !");
            }
            else
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");

                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                string filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                string conString = string.Empty;

                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls": //For Excel 97-03.  
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;

                    case ".xlsx": //For Excel 07 and above.  
                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                        break;
                }

                try
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

                    using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                    {
                        using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                            {
                                cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                                //Get the name of First Sheet.  
                                connExcel.Open();
                                DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                                dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                                string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                          
                                connExcel.Close();

                                //Read Data from First Sheet.  
                                connExcel.Open();
                                cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";

                                odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                                odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                                connExcel.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLOT_TESTING_DB"].ConnectionString;

                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                        {
                            //Set the database table name.  
                            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserTables";
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id", "User_id");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "Email");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserType", "UserType");

                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Department_Name", "DepartmentId");

                            //int dptname = sqlBulkCopy.ParseInt();
                            //sqlBulkCopy.DepartmentId.tryParseToDepartment_Name();

                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TermId", "TermId");

                            //Int32.TryParse(Department.Text, out int x);
                            //Convert.ToInt64("Department_Name");
                            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                            Response.Write("Bulk data stored successfully");
                            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return Json("error" + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        return Json("File uploaded successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create a buffer table and import the data there?

```
sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserTables_Temp";
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id", "User_id");
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "Email");
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserType", "UserType");
sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Department_Name","DepartmentId");
```

Then, having this data in your database, it will be pretty easy to enter in the destination table.

1. First, insert all new department names:

   ```
   INSERT INTO DEpartments (Department_Name)
   SELECT DISTINCT Department_Name
   FROM UserTables_Temp 
   WHERE Department_Name NOT IN (SELECT Department_Name FROM DEpartments)
   ```
2. Now, just make a `INNER JOIN` and insert the new data:

   ```
    INSERT INTO UsersTable ([user_id], [name], email, usertype, departmentid)
    SELECT [user_id], [name], email, usertype, D.[departmentID]
    FROM UserTables_Temp  UT
    INNER JOIN DEpartments D
        ON UD.[Department_Name] = D.[Department_Name]
   ```